# Possible code or library for 2D convolution in C++?

Tags: c++, image-processing, matlab

I need to do 2D convolution using C++. I am looking for a function like MATLAB's conv2 function, but for C++.

I am not looking for any general tips, such as:

- Why don't you use fftw for implementation?
- Why don't you write it yourself for small kernel sizes using for loops?

Because I am 100% sure that many people already have been doing this in a much better way then I will be able to, ever.

Like I said, I am looking for a function like conv2, taking a matrix, a kernel and that let me specify the mode like 'same' http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html?refresh=true

I have been using  Armadillo in the project so far, it only comes with a 1D convolution function. The only library I could come up with providing a 2D convolution is OpenCV. But I would prefer to not add a new giant library only because I am missing one function especially because I am using Qt for displaying graphics.

Any additional suggestions other than OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in contact with the developer of Armadillo, he added a conv2 function.So now Armadillo can be used.

Answer (score 0):

So, it is possible to create C/C++ code from Matlab code, using the [Matlab Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/index.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). If you are willing to use Octave instead, then the Octave libraries can also be used as standalone applications, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs) (which might be even closer to what you are/where looking for).